# Python nltk ImportError

Tags: python, nltk, importerror

I was trying to use nltk for python and then confronted with this problem.

```
>>>from nltk.corpus import sinica_tree
```

and then the error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name sinica_tree
```

I've checked that nltk is installed and that sinica_tree is also installed using nltk.download(). Need some help for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation it looks like it should be:

```
from nltk.corpus import sinica_treebank
```

See: http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>import nltk
>>>nltk.download()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloader> d

Download which package (l=list; x=cancel)?
  Identifier> treebank
```

then try to import

```
from nltk.corpus import sinica_treebank
```